# Looping a grid in canvas HTML5 with "gaps" between squares?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas, grid

I want to create 5x5 grid with 40x40px squares and 4px gaps between them, here's a picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu96a.png

So I intended to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grid').getContext('2d');
    for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
            ctx.fillRect ((40*y)+4*(y+1),(40*x)+4*(x+1),40*(y+1)+4*(y+1),40*(x+1)+4*(x+1));
        };
    };
});
```

But it did not work, I guess there is a simpler way to do it but i just dont know how!
How can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks!

Comment: what did not work? what does this mean "did not work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/H9XeN/),

and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grid').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
    ctx.beginPath();    
    for (var x = 0, i = 0; i < 5; x+=44, i++) {
        for (var y = 0, j = 0; j < 5; y+=44, j++) {            
            ctx.rect (x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
});
```

Another way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grid').getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";    
    for (var x = 0, i = 0; i < 5; x+=44, i++) {
        for (var y = 0, j = 0; j < 5; y+=44, j++) {            
            ctx.fillRect (x, y, 40, 40);
        }
    }
});
```

In both cases I removed `ctx.fillStyle` from the `for` block to improve performance since changes in canvas's state machine slows the drawing process.

**EDIT**:

As pointed by markE in comments, you can use the following approach too:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('grid').getContext('2d');
    var size = 40;
    var offset = 4;

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < 5; y++) {            
            ctx.fillRect (x*(size+offset), y*(size+offset), size, size);
        }
    }
});
```

It's just a matter of personal styling!

Comment: +1 quite right!  Personally I prefer to put any spacers and offsets in the rect drawing itself.  At least for me it's easier to read 6 months from now: ctx.fillRect(x*44+offset,y*44+offset,40,40);  But that's just a matter of personal styling  :)